# Nexus with Private Google container Repo

Tags: docker, authentication, nexus3, google-container-registry

I'm trying to proxy a private Google Container Registry with Nexus 3 Repository OSS. 
Not sure how to do the authentication bit.

I found a suggestion for Artifactory:

1. Create a new Docker remote registry repository
2. Uncheck the Enable Token Authentication flag
3. Set the URL as https://gcr.io
4. Under the advanced tab, set the username as _json_key​
5. Under the advanced tab, set the password to the contents of the JSON Key File

Did not work with Nexus.

Any advice maybe pls ?

Comment: Having the same issue. I do know it's possible with other products, see for example https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-proxy-a-google-container-registry-gcr/. There are some reported bugs that come up if you search Nexus issues for "GCR" or "ACR" (eg. https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-19102), so it *might* have something to do with your version of Nexus.

Comment: You should also check what's in the Nexus logs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a service account with an API Key in order to authenticate,
take a look into this blog that shows how to create the private registry with [Google container registry and Nexus OSS](https://blog.sonatype.com/deploy-private-docker-registry-on-google-cloud-platform-with-nexus).

Comment: Hi, I know that, but the example shows how to deploy Nexus on Google. I have Nexus on prem and would like to configure it to proxy a Private Google Container Registry into Nexus. I have a google service account and the key. now how do I configure the authentication bit in nexus to link to gcr ?

Comment: I'm not sure how does Nexus authenticate , however, I believe that these authentication methods https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication should work with it.